# Writing codebook object to a pdf file with R

Tags: r

I am using a package called "memisic" in order to generate a codebook of my 2000 variables survey. The codebook is pretty much a frequency table with a description and the wordings of the variable name. The package provides a function that is called codebook that results in a codebook object. The problem is that I can't write this object anywhere. I tried to write it to a text file or to pdf file and it doesn't work.

This is a code to generate a codebook (the author's code):

```
  library(memisc)
    Data <- data.set(
    vote = sample(c(1,2,3,8,9,97,99),size=300,replace=TRUE),
    region = sample(c(rep(1,3),rep(2,2),3,99),size=300,replace=TRUE),
    income = exp(rnorm(300,sd=.7))*2000
    )
    Data <- within(Data,{
    description(vote) <- "Vote intention"
    description(region) <- "Region of residence"
    description(income) <- "Household income"
    wording(vote) <- "If a general election would take place next tuesday,
    the candidate of which party would you vote for?"
    wording(income) <- "All things taken into account, how much do all
    household members earn in sum?"
    foreach(x=c(vote,region),{
    measurement(x) <- "nominal"
    })
    measurement(income) <- "ratio"
    labels(vote) <- c(
    Conservatives = 1,
    Labour = 2,
    "Liberal Democrats" = 3,
    "Don't know" = 8,
    "Answer refused" = 9,
    "Not applicable" = 97,
    "Not asked in survey" = 99)
    labels(region) <- c(
    England = 1,
    Scotland = 2,
    Wales = 3,
    "Not applicable" = 97,
    "Not asked in survey" = 99)
    foreach(x=c(vote,region,income),{
    annotation(x)["Remark"] <- "This is not a real survey item, of course ..."
    })
    missing.values(vote) <- c(8,9,97,99)
    missing.values(region) <- c(97,99)
    })
    r=codebook(Data)
```

so my final objective is to write the object R to a pdf/word/excel/text file. Any of these would be just great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to get the text file from this would be to just use `capture.output`:

```
capture.output(r, file="test.txt")
```

Here are the first few lines read back into R:

```
head(readLines("test.txt"))
# [1] "==================================================================================="
# [2] ""                                                                                   
# [3] "   vote 'Vote intention'"                                                           
# [4] ""                                                                                   
# [5] "   \"If a general election would take place next tuesday, the candidate of which"   
# [6] "   party would you vote for?\""
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That works just great. Though now it is a matter of converting this to pdf file while preserving the format.

Comment: Well, I just opened this file from a word document using file> open would open the file preserving the format. Thanks again Ananda.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to output the codebook directly to a txt file using the Write function:

```
Write(codebook(Data), file = "datacodebook.txt")
```